# Any changes in update_member_attribute syntax in APEX5.1 than APEX5.0?

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

We have developed one application using APEX5.0 and its worked without any issues. But, when we updated to apex5.1 then we are facing issues with apex_collection.UPDATE_MEMBER_ATTRIBUTE as below.

Error message -

Ajax call returned server error ORA-06550: line 3, column 4:
PLS-00307: too many declarations of 'UPDATE_MEMBER_ATTRIBUTE' match this call
ORA-06550: line 3, column 4:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored for Execute PL/SQL Code.

Code used -

```
apex_collection.update_member_attribute (
                ' NEW_EMP',
                '1',
                '16',
                'ALBERT');
```

so when I changed above code as below its working without any issues.

```
apex_collection.update_member_attribute (
                p_collection_name =>'NEW_ADJUSTMENT',
                p_seq =>'1',
                p_attr_number =>'16',
                p_attr_value =>'ALBERT');
```

We are seeing this behavior after migrating to APEX5.1 from APEX5.0, could you please tell me is it mandatory to give parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Future readers, answer described here

https://community.oracle.com/message/14196412

There was a bug in 5.1 documentation.